# How do I unzip a file containing entries with accented characters?

Tags: java, character-encoding, zip

I'm trying to write a simple routine to unzip a `.zip` file. Unfortunately, I cannot find a way to achieve this when an entry in the ZIP file contains non-ASCII characters, eg. accented characters from European languages. From what I can see this has long been an issue when working with ZIP files in Java. I haven't been able to get any of the suggestions I've found to work - all of which all focus on encoding.

Here's a couple of my attempts:

```
File file = new File("/tmp/example.zip");
try (ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(file.toURI().toURL().openStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
{
    ZipEntry ze;
    while ((ze = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) {   // <<== Exception thrown here
        System.out.println(ze.getName() + ": " + ze.getSize());
    }
}

try (ZipFile z = new ZipFile(file, StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
{
    Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> entries = z.entries();
    while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {
        ZipEntry ze = entries.nextElement();   // <<== Exception thrown here
        System.out.println(ze.getName() + ": " + ze.getSize());
    }
}
```

The key failure point is the construction of a `ZipEntry` when the entry's name has an accented character, ie. an `IllegalArgumentException` results.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: MALFORMED
    at java.util.zip.ZipCoder.toString(ZipCoder.java:58)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.getZipEntry(ZipFile.java:583)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$900(ZipFile.java:60)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipEntryIterator.next(ZipFile.java:539)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipEntryIterator.nextElement(ZipFile.java:514)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipEntryIterator.nextElement(ZipFile.java:495)
```

If I vary the charset used, I get different results. `US_ASCII` and `UTF_16` result in the same exception. `ISO_8859_1` does not result in an exception, however the accented characters are not decoded correctly.

My test file is created on Windows using the standard "Send to compressed folder" feature. I can unzip the file from the command line correctly.

Update: I tried using the Apache Commons Compress library and ran into essentially the same issue, ie. it too could not handle such entries.

Any thoughts on whether and how I can unzip a ZIP file with entries containing accented characters?

Comment: You must figure out what the original encoding is. What country is this file from?

Comment: I think the original file I had an issue with was from the Netherlands. However, I was able to replicate this issue with a simple ZIP of my own creation. I created a single file with accented characters in its name and zipped it up using the Windows 10 "Send to compressed folder" feature on my laptop in Australia.